# Passing Generic Type into indexOf method JAVA

Tags: java, generics, indexof

I want to use the `indexOf` method to find the number of words, and letters in a String.

indexOf method can accept:

```
indexOf(String s)
indexOf(Char c)
indexOf(String s, index start)
```

So the method can accept **Strings** or **Characters** and can also accept **starting point**

I want to be able to pass either a String or a Character into this method so I have tried to use generics. The code below is main and 2 functions. As you can see I want to be able to have indexOf work with String or Character that I pass in. If I cast 's' in indexOf to a String, it works, but then crashes when it tries to run as Char. Thanks so much in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyStringMethods2 msm = new MyStringMethods2();
    msm.readString();
    msm.printCounts("big", 'a');
}

public <T> void printCounts(T s, T c) {
    System.out.println("***************************************");
    System.out.println("Analyzing sentence = " + myStr);
    System.out.println("Number of '" + s + "' is " + countOccurrences(s));

    System.out.println("Number of '" + c + "' is " + countOccurrences(c));
}

public <T> int countOccurrences(T s) {
    // use indexOf and return the number of occurrences of the string or
    // char "s"
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        index = myStr.indexOf(s, index); //FAILS Here
        if (index != -1) {
            index++;
            count++;
        }
    } while (index != -1);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Method overloading simply doesn't work that way. The three separate `indexOf` methods are essentially unrelated to each other, so you can't use generics to intelligently call one or the other.

Comment: Ahh gosh so not possible basically huh? Unless it was possible to check what type of class the generic object it and then do if (String) then indexOf((String) s, index) & if (Char) then indexOf((Char) s, index)

Answer (score 2):

`String.indexOf` does not use generics.  It takes specific types of parameters.  You should use overloaded methods instead.  Thus:

```
public int countOccurrences(String s) {
    ...
}

public int countOccurrences(char c) {
    return countOccurrences(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

Comment: Yah I originally had it as an overloaded method, but just wanted to see if I could do it this way. But after a bit of research doesn't seem like it is possible with indexOf method which doesn't expect a generic type